# How to apply authenticate directive to only a few routes

Tags: scala, spray

I construct the routes via `~` method. Some of my routes are surrounded with `authenticate` directive which on some circumstances returns rejections. I have an implicit rejection handler in scope of `runRoute` method.

How to apply this directive to only routes that are surrounded with this directive? In rejectionHandler I perform redirect to path which is not surrounded with authenticate directive. In debug I figured out that the second request(after redirection) also goes through my `contextAuthenticator`

**EDIT**
Example of using `authenticate` directive

```
val securedRoutes = authenticate(myContextAuthenticator) { implicit user =>
  route1 ~
  route2  
}
```

Here `myContextAuthenticator` is of type `ContextAuthenticator[User]`

and `receive` method is

```
def receive = runRoute {
    otherRoutes  ~ securedRoutes
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are using the `authenticate` directive?

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit rejection handler is suitable for nonrecoverable, global rejections that should be converted corresponding HTTP responses like 400 or 404.

However, if you need to handle rejections specific to a route, in your case authenticated routes, spray has [handleRejections](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/execution-directives/handleRejections/#handlerejections) directive.

Simple usage would be like this:

```
val authenticatedRoute = handleRejections(myAuthenticatorRejectionHandler) &
  authenticate(myContextAuthenticator)

val securedRoutes = authenticatedRoute { implicit user =>
  route1 ~
  route2  
}
```

Comment: strange, but in my case implicit rejection handler always takes precedence for routes defined as in your example

Comment: I guess I know why. Order of handlerejections and authenticate should be opposite. I updated my answer.